# STM32 Hardfault when trying to access memory

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

I am analyzing code written for STM32H730 microcontroller. I find the below snippet of code which is giving hardfault when the BootHoldRequest(&fnBoot) is called.

```
#define BOOTBLOCK_ADD        0x08000000L
#define BootHoldRequest        (*((BOOTLOAD_PROCEED_TYPE *) (BOOTBLOCK_ADD + 0x200)))

typedef void (* CALLBACK_PTR)(void);
typedef uint16_t BOOTLOAD_PROCEED_TYPE(CALLBACK_PTR *);

typedef void (* VOID_FUN_TYPE)(void);
static VOID_FUN_TYPE fnBoot;

if (BootHoldRequest(&fnBoot)) //<--------- HARDFAULT
{
       
}
```

Comment: What does your memory map for the device look like? Are you sure that the addresses presented will be correct?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have changed the BOOTBLOCK_ADD to 0x08000000L which is the correct address according to reference manual. Still getting hardfault.

Comment: How did a function of the expected type end up at that address?

Comment: Also how does `BootHoldRequest(&fnBoot)` make sense? It isn't a valid function-like macro. How did you manage to get this compiling?

Comment: @Lundin `BootHoldRequest` is a macro that casts a value (an address) into a pointer to a function, and then that function is called.

Comment: Are you sure that `if ((*((BOOTLOAD_PROCEED_TYPE *) (0x08000000UL + 0x200)))(&fnBoot))` is exactly what you want. Please explain what construction should do.

Comment: Are you sure that you have at the address `0x08000000UL + 0x200` the address of the function to call?

Comment: What is the value at `BOOTBLOCK_ADD + 0x200`?  Is it a valid Thumb2 jump address?  It must be `function_address + 1`.

Comment: If the linker has placed the address there it will have bit0 set. Same as entries in the vector table

Comment: @0___________ ; I deleted the comment already  There is nothing you cannot confuse with yet one more level of indirection ;-)

Comment: Indeed, but if not you'd get a UsageFault (promoted to HardFault is UsageFault not enabled) so it is a reasonable question.  No one has provided evidence that this was linker generated.  I am only stating what any reasonable developer would check.

Comment: @Clifford if you want to be extremely safe you should OR with 1 but never add 1 as in your answer which will most certainly lead to the disaster.

Comment: Are you certain it is faulting at the call rather then _inside_ the function?  How did you arrive at that conclusion.  Clearly there is insufficient information in  the question - you need to fix that.

Comment: @0___________ : Yes agreed, did not initially note the cast to function-pointer.

Comment: @Clifford It is written absolutely horrible way. Hard to read. Even integer constant has wrong type :)

Answer (score 1):

As it is impossible to answer your question not seeing the whole project (including linker scripts etc) I will only show how to debug this issue.

1. What does this code do?

```
if (BootHoldRequest(&fnBoot))

        ldr     r0, .L6
        ldr     r3, .L6+4
        bx      r3
.L6:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
        .word   0x8000200
```

It loads the 4 bytes address from the `BOOTBLOCK_ADD + 0x200` location and then next calls code located at this address. I do not know if you have the correct data there so you need to check it yourself.

If you use IDE (in my example Atollic - which is almost identical with STM32Cube IDE) you can easily check it.

Two methods:
Set the breakpoint at this line.

1. Use the expression window to see what is at this address:
   [image]
2. Enter the instruction debug mode
   [image]

And follow the code one assembly instruction at the time. You will see if the code does what it is supposing to do.
[image]
It is not your code. It is the code from my project I work on.